Beautiful soup indeed scrape
Im trying to scrape data from the indeed website and wanted to first make a transform function that finds all the divs that have this section and return the length:

My code keeps returning zero and I can't quite understand why.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract(page):
    headers = {'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0'}
    url = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&start={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'cardOutline tapItem dd-privacy-allow')
    return len(divs)

#extract everything from page one and stored in variable
c = extract(0)

#prints length of every instance the class_ argument shows up in the extracted data
print(transform(c))


What does r return?

Did you notice the HTTP 403 error?

The Indeed site uses Cloudflare's bot protection. You can verify this by checking the cookies in your browser. Therefore, it's not feasible to retrieve content using the requests library. Please consider alternative solutions.
